# Сложный алгоритм анализа данных

Tags: база-данных, машинное-обучение

Привет коллегам!
Есть база данных с набором полей.
Например так:

```
Рейтинг 1   Величина 1  Рейтинг 2  Величина 2   Результат 1   Результат 2
  40        20            100          -120         2            0
  30        10            200          450          2            1
```

Ну и тд

Требуется выбрать комбинации значений полей, которые приводят к результату 2.
Например при рейтинге 1 > рейтинга 2 и величине 2 < величины 2:  90% записей приводят к результату со значением '2'.

Может посоветуете, что почитать, может какие-то библиотеки есть или типовые алгоритмы?

Comment: ясно что ничего не ясно. больше примеров. при чем тут вероятности и комбинации

Comment: Тут нет конкретного готового алгоритма на все случаи жизни. Вам предстоит освоить обширную дисциплину известную как машинное обучение. Начните с [классификаторов на деревьях решений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: ...А еще начать можно с этого: https://habrahabr.ru/company/ods/blog/322626/ (в pandas можно добавлять свои столбцы, а еще у DataFrame есть замечательные методы groupby и mean)

Comment: Суть такова, что нужно найти как можно более высокий %  комбинаций значений, которые приводят к опредленном результату, ну например можно сравнить со ставками на футбол, критерии такие: выше или ниже команда в рейтинге, играет дома или на выезде, количество игр в сезоне   - значения величин и результат - выиграла команда или проиграла, при каких комбинациях.